# iOS - implementing SFGaugeView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I want to add [SFGaugeView](https://github.com/simpliflow/SFGaugeView) to my app.

When I create UIView in storyboard, change class to SFGaugeView and connect Outlet, than all works great. But... When I do it programmatically (which is what I need), it doesn't work.

Here is my progress:

```
#import SFGaugeView.h
```

Than, I've set property (`@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet SFGaugeView *middleTachometer;`) in .h file

and in .m file, I have this code:

```
self.middleTachometer = [[SFGaugeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 504)];
self.middleTachometer.bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:175/255.0 blue:102/255.0 alpha:1];
self.middleTachometer.needleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:27/255.0 green:103/255.0 blue:107/255.0 alpha:1];
self.middleTachometer.maxlevel = 10;
self.middleTachometer.minImage = @"minImage";
self.middleTachometer.maxImage = @"maxImage";

SFGaugeView *viewC = [[SFGaugeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 504)];

[viewC addSubview:self.middleTachometer];
[self.view addSubview:viewC];
```

Result is that Gauge is in view, but it does not interact to gestures (and with storyboard, it does). Where is problem please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have two SFGaugeViews? I think changing your code like this:

```
self.middleTachometer = [[SFGaugeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 504)];
self.middleTachometer.bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:175/255.0  blue:102/255.0 alpha:1];
self.middleTachometer.needleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:27/255.0 green:103/255.0 blue:107/255.0 alpha:1];
self.middleTachometer.maxlevel = 10;
self.middleTachometer.minImage = @"minImage";
self.middleTachometer.maxImage = @"maxImage";

[self.view addSubview:self.middleTachometer];
```

should do the trick!

EDIT:
Okay, got me interested - I've recreated a test project, and the problem is acutally in the SFGaugeView class - when manually adding it, the `setup` method is never called. 
So you can either manually call the `awakeFromNIB` method or wait for my pull request (https://github.com/simpliflow/SFGaugeView/pull/1) to be merged in!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no, still doesn't interact.. :(

Comment: Okay, i've tried it out myself and found the error in SFGaugeView :) Check the Pullrequest for the change in SFGaugeView (simple) or just call the awakeFromNIB manually - but that's bad style!